# Calculate CRC-5 using boost

Tags: c++, boost, rfid, crc

I need to calculate a CRC-5 checksum as specified in the EPC passive RFID protocol standard [(UHF Class 1 Gen 2 Standard)](http://www.gs1.org/gsmp/kc/epcglobal/uhfc1g2/uhfc1g2_1_2_0-standard-20080511.pdf). I intend to use the [optimized crc computer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/crc/crc.html) from Boost for the calculations, but I'm having a difficult time mapping the information from the EPC specification to the crc computer template parameters:

```
template < std::size_t Bits, impl_def TruncPoly,
           impl_def InitRem, impl_def FinalXor,
           bool ReflectIn, bool ReflectRem >
```

The CRC 5 definition from the EPC standard can be found in table 6.12:
[image]

Annex F contains this additional information:
[image]

The first template parameter (Bits) is obviously 5, and I suppose that TruncPoly should be 0x09 (from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_representations_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks)), but I could really use some advice for the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more searching I found this: http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat-bits.5

It provides the following information (copied to ensure that it doesn't disappear):
[image]

In case it is not clearly visible, the relevant information is:

> width=5 poly=0x09 init=0x09 refin=false refout=false xorout=0x00
>   check=0x00 name="CRC-5/EPC"

As you can see, they don't just give the information needed, they also thoroughly reference their sources, so I can recommend to follow the link if you're working with this.

To answer my own question, the boost crc-5-epc definition then becomes:

```
boost::crc_optimal<5, 0x09, 0x09, 0x00, false, false>  crc_5_epc;
```